# How do I prevent ubuntu one from connecting automatically?

Tags: 13.04, ubuntu-one

I actually use ubuntu one sometimes. So I didn't plan on uninstalling it.

It starts up automatically upon login.
It is not listed in my startup applications.

In ubuntu1 settings I unchecked connect automatically on start-up but it continues to do so.

I changed my password using the online web form.  Somehow my ubuntu one installation already knows the password thus continues to connect automatically.

Creep factor rising.

Comment: Are you asking about connecting, or starting? If you've unchecked `Connect automatically when computer starts` in the control panel, then it will not connect to the server on start.

Comment: Connecting. But if that isn't possible then starting.

Comment: I just realised that it is actually disconnected after checking that box.  It just says On when I click on the indicator. This lead me to believe that it was connected. If I go into Ubuntu One it indeed says disconnected. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Opening the `Ubuntu One` application from the launcher, switching to the *Settings* tab, and unchecking the *Connect automatically when computer starts* setting, will disable connecting to the server when the client starts.

Also, Ubuntu One does not store your password locally. It acquires an OAuth token when you log in from the client, and stores that. However, changing your password on the server should cause the token to be revoked, but there may be a bug where the authentication server and the file synchronization server get desynchronized in the process.